# Mounting the WP7 VHD file

Tags: security, windows-phone-7, mount, vhd

According to wiki, VHD (Virtual Hard Disk) may contain what is found on a physical HDD, such as disk partitions and a file system, which in turn can contain files and folders.

I have found the VHD image of the WP7 in the following directory.

[image: VHD screenshot]

I read that Hyper-V features offline VHD manipulation, providing administrators with the ability to securely access files within a VHD without having to instantiate a virtual machine. The Windows Disk Management MMC plugin can directly attach a .vhd as a drive letter in Windows 7. I tried the same thing.

[image]

The result was this error.

[image]

Now, I want to know if there is anyway to mount this VHD and explore the file system ? I mean can I take this VHD to a linux environment and explore ? Is this VHD really corrupt or I lack some access privileges ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it too, but get the same message as you get. Probably a kind of restriction Microsoft has build in to protect users from sniffing around. (Especially in the period that there where no hardware devices and only the emulator was available or periods where the updated SDK is delivered earlier than the actual update)

If there is a way too mount this VHD than they definitly know how to do it at the [XDA developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=605). I think posting your question overthere will result in more/better answers than on StackOverflow which has more focus on application development.